# Safely reset (including running js) complete page to just like blank page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

We provide live chat service to our customers. customer just copy some code and put in their footer. then they can have video chat, cobrowsing and many things..

but problem comes when user switch from page to page. so we have resume functionality as well. but thats not robost solution.

So i've come to two solution.

**1. Iframe solution**

i'll give client a some.html file which he'll need to upload to their root url, then upon video chat and cobrowse we load that page in some.html's iframe and chat appear in some.html

so that work well. chat box apprear seamlessly no page reload effects came in. and as its on same domain i can access all contents of iframe.

**2. Another hack solution** (not implemented yet, looks good solution)

i was thinking that instead of redirecting user to new page (some.html)
i should clear all contents of current page and load same url in one iframe within the page.

i think that will work well. but i affraid that some client might be using complex js based web app. so if i remove complete body from their page they might have problems.

**as much as i know i can remove all dom nodes with their events handlers as well. but is their way to clean js runtime. so all js objects will destroyed and removed from scope so no longer run.**

**so is there a ways to clear any page completely with all its html and associated java-script as well. means reset page to blank.**

Comment: Whats the wrong, why its goes -1, am i asked wrong question at wrong place.?

Comment: the correct answer is to correct your chat script, not to mess with the clients website. that's a great way to lose clients.

Comment: i am looking for solution and definalty we have implemented both solution and client will see disclaimer as well.. so client can choose one of these 3  methods

Comment: Both "solutions" will degrade, and possibly break, your customers website in some way or another. Your technical challenges should in no way make your customers and their users experience worse. What about opening the chat in a new (pop-up) window?

Comment: Its my clients, i am not asking how to make my clients happy or how make good UI, i am asking programming related question. if don't have answer then fine. not problem..

Comment: even still, you didn't post any code.

Comment: what code sholud i show you? i am asking how to reset page, if knew then i could search myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found that there is no way to reset page.. but got another way to make it done.

upon need we can redirect user to same page with query string that identity that its reload for iframe, we put small bit of another code at head which remove all dom before loading dom, css, js.. and create just one iframe of same url.

thus it allows me, have user see no change in url, user browse website as normal without any problem and my chatbox always be there in same state across all pages.

will make it live soon on tagove.com

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you empty the HTML page using empty() function of jquery first,

Then remove/update the link i.e.`<script src="...."></script>` so that the HTML has no dependency on that javascript and that way it won't be able to Modify the DOM.
And then try to build a javascript program to remove any file in the folder which is isolated(No calling, No dependency, no connection whatsoever)

Comment: also, this is an awful idea.

Comment: @Pamblam there's `jQuery.empty()` method which this answer clearly refers to. I don't know what for, but that's another matter.

Comment: Well @Pamblam clearly while you don't get what i just said, You might as well read the question clearly (the last bold line specifically). I just gave him an Idea. as he tried couple of things which certainly reflect this is a complicated situation

Comment: you don't need worry about client's website

Comment: While this is what he is looking for (Last bold line - if you can read it?).  - I gave him an Idea.

Comment: And I just asked to empty the DOM in chat Box Only not the whole website.

Comment: yes no worry about my chatbox or my js, i'll figure out that later, but right now i am looking for destory page.. so when desktory for client it will seen like user is gone..

Comment: because i don't want remove dom and keep running client's javascriptts. because without dom his js will not work that will make issues, Thats why i want to remove both.

Comment: When any javascript is not connected, its already Dead, it is not necessary to delete or remove the script.

Comment: if there is a file which is not being imported or if no file has a dependency on a other file even it is storage is metaphorically dead. it has no significance.please keep in mind it is untrue for a file which is specailly build to hack

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103615/discussion-between-dev-mraj-and-dewy-sady).